# Combine last values from timestamp columns across several tables - into a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are several tables in the database each containing a column with the same name, "timestamp":

Table 1:

| UniqueID | timestamp | other columns ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-15 00:00:00.000 | ... |
| ... | 2022-02-15 00:00:00.000 | ... |
| 43374082 | 2023-04-11 00:00:00.000 | ... |

Table 2:

| UniqueID | timestamp | other columns ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-15 00:00:00.000 | ... |
| ... | 2022-02-15 00:00:00.000 | ... |
| 54364 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000 | ... |

... and a couple more similar tables.

How does one go about taking the **last row's** timestamps from each table and combining them in a table like this?

Combo table:

| Table Name | last timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| Table 1 | 2023-04-11 00:00:00.000 |
| Table 2 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000 |

The ultimate goal is to check several tables in a database for how long ago they were last updated (last row's timestamps), and display these timestamps in a readable (and scalable and sortable) format.

The code how to get the last timestamps from each table it likely something like this:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 timestamp
    FROM [Table 1]
    ORDER BY UniqueID DESC
```

... yet I am not sure how to put these timestamps into a single table together with source table names.

---

Edit 1:

Someone or something came up with this code that does what I need:

```
WITH #CTE_Table1 AS (
    SELECT 'Table 1' AS [Table Name], timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [Table 1]
),
#CTE_Table2 AS (
    SELECT 'Table 2' AS [Table Name], timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [Table 2]
),
#CTE_Table3 AS (
    SELECT 'Table 3' AS [Table Name], timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [Table 3]
),
#CTE_Table4 AS (
    SELECT 'Table 4' AS [Table Name], timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [Table 4]
),
#CTE_Table5 AS (
    SELECT 'Table 5' AS [Table Name], timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UniqueID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM [Table 5]
)

SELECT [Table Name], [Last Timestamp]
FROM (
    SELECT [Table Name], timestamp AS [Last Timestamp], RowNum
    FROM #CTE_Table1
    WHERE RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Table Name], timestamp AS [Last Timestamp], RowNum
    FROM #CTE_Table2
    WHERE RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Table Name], timestamp AS [Last Timestamp], RowNum
    FROM #CTE_Table3
    WHERE RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Table Name], timestamp AS [Last Timestamp], RowNum
    FROM #CTE_Table4
    WHERE RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Table Name], timestamp AS [Last Timestamp], RowNum
    FROM #CTE_Table5
    WHERE RowNum = 1


) AS [Last Timestamp];
```

Output:

| Table Name | Last Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| Table 1 | 2023-04-11 00:00:00.000 |
| Table 2 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000 |
| Table 3 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000 |
| Table 4 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000 |
| Table 5 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000 |

... which works - yet I am not happy with it: from the little I know of SQL, the code doesn't seem to be of high quality or easily readable.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not completely obvious what you're asking but it sounds like you need a view that will return the max() timestamp column from several tables unioned together.

Comment: With a few tables you need a union, with lots of tables you need to join all tables by timestamp and pivot them

Comment: Fyi your ChatGPT answer is a) not in keeping with the site policy and b) pretty abysmal the proposed answer is a better solution.

Comment: thanks @Stu - forgot about that policy...

Comment: Please don't edit your question with your solution. Add your solution as an answer if its significantly different from the other answers.

Comment: And don't add new questions about answers to your question, ask that as a comment under the answer - your own if you add it.

Comment: P.S. I can see it's abysmal - but it works - while the proposed answer generates "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'." in MS SQL.

Comment: @DaleK: don't want to add an answer that I know to be of poor quality. Plus, the platform does ask to include "what have you tried?" in the question. (Isn't that also an abuse of the platform, adding answers that I know to be of poor quality?)

Comment: 1) You've added what you tried **after** you asked the question and received an answer... 2) That changes your question from "how to solve this problem" to "is this the best way to solve the problem" (which you should never do). 3) If your answer solves the problem as stated then its perfect to add it as a answer. The fact that its based on the existing answer which has 3 upvotes should tell you that its not a poor approach.

Comment: And SO isn't a code review site, its a technical problem solving site. So questions asking "is my code following best practices" will get closed as opinion based, because there is not only one right answer.

Comment: @Stu: `max()` scans the entire table while `top 1` / `order by` / `desc` doesn't, making `max()` a poorly performing solution in large tables. Does that sound right? 

Also: is it clear what it's asking now that it's been edited?

Comment: Respectfully, disagree: I am still seeking the answer to the original question. Will be happy to edit the question to make it clear. P.S. are upvotes in direct correlation to the answer quality? Or perhaps, in a loose one? :)

Comment: Updated the question, @DaleK. :) A little better?

Comment: But you're not seeking an answer to your original question, you now have a query which produces the results. You're asking if its a "good" query... to which we can't answer unless you provide metrics to define good. In SQL land if it produces the required result quickly, then its probably OK. SQL is not like other languages where you are trying to make DRY/Single responsibility etc. SQL is very very different.

Comment: @kindzmarauli regarding "max" - analysing the specific performance of a query is different from does this query work - SQL is a declarative language which you should write to describe what result you want without being concerned with the "how". Whether one specific approach is better than another is a separate issue but depends on many factors, none of which are really relevant to the primary question - what you mean by large is not what I mean by large - using Max certainly does *not* mean a scan if an appropriate index is available and using top with order-by still requires sorted data.

Comment: @kindzmarauli I've no idea if this represents a "large" table but [here I have top() and max() performing identically on a 52m row table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olxML.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union all`, and pass the table name as a literal value.

It is a bit tricky because in SQL Server we can't use `order by` directly in `union all` members, so we need subqueries. Assuming that all of your tables have columns `ts` (timestamp) and `uniqueID` (for ordering):

```
select 'table1' as table_name, (select top 1 ts from table1 order by uniqueId desc) as last_ts
union all select 'table2',     (select top 1 ts from table2 order by uniqueId desc)
union all select 'table3',     (select top 1 ts from table3 order by uniqueId desc)
```

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'."

Comment: True! You can only order the final results in a union all.

Comment: You would actually need each query to be a derived table ie within parenthesis but the basic principle is sound

Comment: @kindzmarauli: ahh yes, my bad, we can't use `order by` like that in `union`. I changed the query in my answer...

Comment: It's alive!!! (I.e. it *works*!) Thanks @GMB!